# PostgreSQL to Oracle - Can i change OWNER in Oracle?

Tags: postgresql, oracle11g, schema

I am trying to edit PostgreSQL schema script and make it executable in Oracle (Oracle Express). In PostgreSQL were under the each CREAT TABLE these commands:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name OWNER TO user;
```

For example table_name is *appuser* and user is *projectX*.

The table is successfully created, but there is an error: ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option

I have also created another user in my scheme (projectX), but the error is still there. So I am confused. Does this command ALTER TABLE table_name OWNER TO user; even exists in Oracle database?

Comment: No that's not possible. The owner of a table cannot be changed in Oracle. All valid `ALTER` statements in Oracle are documented in the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/toc.htm The only way to do this, is to drop the table and re-create it as the new owner. (And you don't really need that line in Postgres in the first place).

Comment: Trying to run DDL scripts verbatim on a different database is also generally not a good way to port a schema. I'm amazed it works to the point where you can run the CREATE TABLE statements, given how often data type names vary from DB to DB.

Comment: Thanks a lot! And i did not create the postgreSQL schema. The "alter table owner to" has maybe generated the postreSQL itself, when i exported the schema :)